# How to fix faker.date.past deprecation warning

Tags: node.js, node-modules, faker.js

I found multiple deprecation warnings such as:

```js
import { faker } from '@faker-js/faker';

const pastDate = faker.date.past(1);
const futureDate = faker.date.future(2);
const betweenDate = faker.date.between('2001-02-02', '2002-02-02');
const recentDate = faker.recent(7);
```

Any idea how to fix it?

Answer (score 1):

With the release of **version 8.0**, Faker.js introduced a significant change in their API. Methods now accept a single options object as a parameter, rather than multiple individual arguments.

This modification allows for greater flexibility and readability. Here's how you can adapt your code to this new approach:

```js
import { faker } from '@faker-js/faker';

// Instead of faker.date.past(1), use:
const pastDate = faker.date.past({ years: 1 });

// Instead of faker.date.future(2), use:
const futureDate = faker.date.future({ years: 2 });

// Instead of faker.date.between('2001-02-02', '2002-02-02'), use:
const betweenDate = faker.date.between({ from: '2001-02-02', to: '2002-02-02' });

// Instead of faker.recent(7), use:
const recentDate = faker.recent({ days: 7 });
```

By replacing individual parameters with an options object, you can take full advantage of Faker's updated API and create more readable and maintainable code.